# Gridview or better?

Tags: asp.net, .net, linq

I know my post might sounds a bit silly BUT: 
I ve learn asp.net by myself and now I'm wondering if there's better way than gridview to simply present data with linq with features like sort/filter / update / insert / delete...

If gridview are still common, what's the best way to implement them?

Thanks in advance for your answers

Comment: All the cool kids are using MVC this week.

Comment: Have a look at **http://datatables.net/** which you can use like a gridview

Answer (score 1):

Use **ListView**, that gives you more control over output and behavior. It works perfectly in connection with **DataSource** controls and **DataPager**.

[Here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/10/the-asp-listview-control-part-1-building-a-product-listing-page-with-clean-css-ui.aspx) you can find an extremely detailed tutorial by the ASP.NET guru Scott Guthrie.

Comment: Thanx a lot it will be helpfull.